# How can I upgrade Linux MInt from 19.3 to 20.1?

Tags: linux-mint, upgrade

I suspect I'm missing something basic, but:

Linux Mint 20.1 is now available. What I understand a standard upgrade is to open Update Manager, and under the Edit menu select a fourth, bottom entry to upgrade Mint.

However, when I pull up Update Manager, the Edit menu has Preferences, System Snapshots, and Software Sources.

I have run, for instance, an aptitude update and aptitude upgrade since linuxmint.com said 20.1 was available.

TIA,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal and run `sudo -i`, then

```
curl 'https://pastebin.com/raw/9mdbf0YA' | bash
```

at your own risk. Beware that some PPAs might not yet be updated for the new version.

Here is the full code:

```
curl 'https://pastebin.com/raw/xqivHSvC' | bash
sed -i 's/tricia/ulyana/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
sed -i 's/bionic/focal/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
sed -i 's/bionic/focal/g' /etc/lsb-release
apt update
apt full-upgrade
apt autoremove --purge
apt autoclean
reboot
```

Comment: The (additional) `sudo`'s shouldn't be needed for the `sed` lines if they're being run from an interactive root shell.

Comment: Also, I usually use `aptitude`, but I noticed I had to specifically run `apt autoremove` as `aptitude autoremove` gave "Here's how to use this program." output.

Comment: @ChristosHayward I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Linux Mint releases at least Ulyana (Linux Mint 20) as available to download and install from scratch something like 1-2 weeks before an upgrade from a previous version of Linux Mint is offered.

So in short an upgrade from previous versions has a delayed release.